# Can a php script called using Ajax post send back SSE events while the script executes

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a php script on my server that performs multiple tasks (setting up folders, copying files etc) and I call the script with ajax.

i.e

signup.js:

```
const evtSource = new EventSource("/createuser.php", { withCredentials: true } );
evtSource.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log(event.data);
}

$.ajax({
    type:     'POST',
    url:      '/createuser.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'username': "test user", 
        'usertype' : "author"
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log("user created");
    }
});
```

now on createuser.php I try and send a message to my webpage:

createuser.php:

```
<?php
function SendProgressMessage($op){
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

    switch($op){
        case "userCreated":
            echo "User Created";
        break;
        case "foldersCreated":
            echo "Folder structure created";
        break;
        case "TemplatesCopied":
            echo "Templates Copied";
        break;
    }
    flush();
}
?>
```

can i setup the evtSource to the same script and the ajax call or does 2 session get created to the script?

Comment: Why would you do both?

Comment: What does that code do? `SendProgressMessage` is never called

Comment: This is just a small section of the my creation script that is relevant.  SendProgressMessage is called by other scripts when certain tasks are completed.  The initial call is done by ajax because I need to post data to createuser.php and do something when the task is completed.  Instead of polling the script I just wondered if I could utilize SSE to inform my new user of the progress of the account creation.

Comment: "The initial call is done by ajax"  That's not the order of things that you have above though.  Call the ajax, and put the EventSource code in the success callback.

Comment: Sorry I should of said my ajax call is what calls the script to do the actual work. I realize now that what i'm trying to achieve can't be done this way as Lars advises below.  As createuser.php sets up my users environment which can take between 20/30 seconds to complete I have to rethink the way I inform the user of the progress and using a db to do this is probably the best way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set it up like this, the AJAX request will result in an new PHP process on the server side, which isn't aware of the first process.

The long-working script should store the status into a database, from where it can be queried independently by a second(, third, ...) request.

Comment: thanks for confirmation,  I suspected this was the case and will create a db to store the updates then query them via an iframe on my modal.